# gentoo can not use overlay

Tags: overlay, gentoo

my os is gentoo

i want to update x11-libs/cairo from lcd-filtering overlay, so

```
#layman --version
1.4.1
#layman -a lcd-filtering
```

and then

```
#echo 'source "/var/lib/layman/make.conf"' >> /etc/make.conf
#layman -l
* lcd-filtering    [Git       ] (git://gitorious.org/lcd-filtering/lcd-filtering.git
```

now i reinstall cairo

```
# emerge -pv x11-libs/cairo
[ebuild   R    ] x11-libs/cairo-1.10.2-r2  USE="X glib opengl svg xcb (-aqua) -debug -directfb -doc (-drm) (-gallium) (-openvg) (-qt4) -static-libs" 0 kB
Total: 1 package (1 reinstall), Size of downloads: 0 kB
```

it isn't install from lcd-filtering overlay, how can i slove this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a programming issue, or an OS install problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're running Gentoo with a stable ACCEPT_KEYWORDS (i.e. amd64, not ~amd64). The overlay version is not marked as stable. 1.10.2-r2 is the latest stable version in the Portage tree. You can't specifically force an overlay to take priority so you have two options...

- Change KEYWORDS in the overlay version to make it stable.
- Add "x11-libs/cairo ~amd64" to /etc/portage/package.keywords and add ">=x11-libs/cairo-1.11" to /etc/portage/package.mask.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in such situation is try and find out the mentioned keywords by either emerge -S or running eix-update (provided you have it installed) and then checking it with eix (which is handy anyways).